How to parse CFG with operators
Ok so I have this parser and data:
module SO where

import Data.Char
import Prelude hiding (fmap, (>>=), (*>), (<*), pure)
data Parser a = MkParser (String -> Maybe (String, a))

data Expr
    = Num Integer
    | Var String
    | Prim2 Op2 Expr Expr       -- Prim2 op operand operand
    | Let [(String, Expr)] Expr -- Let [(name, rhs), ...] body
    deriving Show

data Op2 = Add | Sub | Mul | Pow
    deriving Show

and this is the parser:
powsV1 :: Parser Expr
powsV1 = fmap Num natural
         >>= \x ->     ((operator "^" *> pure (Prim2 Pow))
                        >>= \op -> powsV1
                        >>= \y -> pure (op x y))
                   <|>
                       pure x

The parser uses a lot of helpers. Here they are:
natural :: Parser Integer
natural = fmap read (some (satisfy isDigit)) <* whitespaces

-- | Space or tab or newline (unix and windows).
whitespace :: Parser Char
whitespace = satisfy (\c -> c `elem` ['\t', '\n', '\r', ' '])

-- | Consume zero or more whitespaces, maximum munch.
whitespaces :: Parser String
whitespaces = many whitespace

many :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
many p = some p <|> pure []

some :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
some p = liftA2 (:) p (many p)

liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> Parser a -> Parser b -> Parser c
liftA2 op (MkParser sf1) p2 = MkParser g
  where
    g inp = case sf1 inp of
              Nothing -> Nothing
              Just (middle, a) ->
                  case unParser p2 middle of
                    Nothing -> Nothing
                    Just (rest, b) -> Just (rest, op a b)


(<*) :: Parser a -> Parser b -> Parser a
pa <* pb = liftA2 (\a _ -> a) pa pb

(*>) :: Parser a -> Parser b -> Parser b
pa *> pb = liftA2 (\_ b -> b) pa pb

satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
satisfy pred = MkParser sf
  where
    sf (c:cs) | pred c = Just (cs, c)
    sf _ = Nothing


unParser :: Parser a -> String -> Maybe (String, a)
unParser (MkParser sf1) = sf1

(<|>) :: Parser a -> Parser a -> Parser a
MkParser sf1 <|> p2 = MkParser g
  where
    g inp = case sf1 inp of
              Nothing -> unParser p2 inp
              j -> j        -- the Just case

empty :: Parser a
empty = MkParser (\_ -> Nothing)

-- | Read something that looks like an operator, then skip trailing spaces.
anyOperator :: Parser String
anyOperator = some (satisfy symChar) <* whitespaces
  where
    symChar c = c `elem` "!#$%&*+-./:<=>?@\\^|~"


-- | Read the wanted operator, then skip trailing spaces.
operator :: String -> Parser String
operator wanted =
    anyOperator
    >>= \sym -> if sym == wanted then pure wanted else empty

fmap :: (a -> b) -> Parser a -> Parser b
fmap f (MkParser sf) = MkParser sfb
  where
    sfb inp = case sf inp of
                Nothing -> Nothing
                Just (rest, a) -> Just (rest, f a)


(>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
MkParser sf1 >>= k = MkParser g
  where
    g inp = case sf1 inp of
              Nothing -> Nothing
              Just (rest, a) -> unParser (k a) rest

pure :: a -> Parser a
pure a = MkParser (\inp -> Just (inp, a))

My question is regarding this:
powsV1 :: Parser Expr
powsV1 = fmap Num natural
         >>= \x ->     ((operator "^" *> pure (Prim2 Pow))
                        >>= \op -> powsV1
                        >>= \y -> pure (op x y))
                   <|>
                       pure x

I'm stepping through the code to understand it. Let's take 2^3^4 as an example:
fmap Num natural simply parses a number. So we have 2. It passes it to \x ->     ((operator "^" *> pure (Prim2 Pow)). This parses ^ and gives Prim2 Pow to \op -> powsV1. This is recursive. 3 gets parsed, passes it to ((operator "^" *> pure (Prim2 Pow)). ^ get's parsed, and pure (Prim2 Pow) is passed to \op -> powsV1.
We recurse again, 5 gets parsed. passes it to ((operator "^" *> pure (Prim2 Pow)). This fails as nothing is after 5. So it gives <|> pure x which is just 5. 5 is now the y in \y -> pure (op x y)). So we have Prim2 Pow 4 5 and this is now the y to the first pow. So we have Prim2 Pow (Num 3) (Prim2 Pow (Num 4) (Num 5))).
Now I want to try this (my question is here): 3^z
3 gets parsed, passes it as x to \x ->     ((operator "^" *> pure (Prim2 Pow)).
^ get's parsed, and it then gives pure (Prim2 Pow) to >>= \op -> powsV1.
We recurse, and it fails because z is not a number. Because of this fail, the code jumps to <|> pure x. So now it gives the original x which is 3. But at this point ^ is already parsed, right? So what would the output be?
I ran the code like this:
MkParser p = powsV1 
p "3^z"

And this gave Just ("^z",Num 3) But I am not sure what steps it took to print it?
I feel like I'm misunderstanding how the () are being used, or at what point the second part of (<|>) is used.

p1 <|> p2 saves the input state before trying p1.
If p1 fails, it uses that saved input to backtrack and try p2.
So in this case, the input "^z" fails, and the result is a successful parse of 3 with "^z" as the unconsumed input.
As an optimisation, some parsing libraries like Parsec and Megaparsec will only save the backtracking state when you explicitly opt into that with a try combinator. With those libraries, p1 <|> p2 can only backtrack if p1 doesn’t consume any input. With the parser you have here, backtracking is always allowed, and can “give back” input in the event of failure.
